# How to make my switch button center it self

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not sure whether its possible to do this, but look at this switch button:
[Switch button location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi2cz.png)

So what I am trying to do is to move it at the exact center, where it should be on the red square location: [Center location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edUK8.png)

Just to let you know that I have tried:

```
android:gravity="center" // didn't work
android:layout_gravity="center"// didn't work
android:foregroundGravity="center"// didn't work
```

this is my full xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25">

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ubersign" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:text="Driver"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:onClick="switchOnOf" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:text="Rider"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Get Started" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25">

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So is there any possible way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can keep the LinearLayour and do the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Driver"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="switchOnOf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Rider"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Driver"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="switchOnOf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch3"
        android:text="Rider"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of `android:layout_weight="20"` to `android:layout_weight="10"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:text="Driver"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:onClick="switchOnOf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:text="Rider"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```